# how to save user text input html input as cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a lot of trouble writing HTML that is intermingled with JavaScript.
I have a input box that  assigns the input to a variable. I want that input box to assign the input to the cookie and if there is a cookie entered in the site it redirects you. Now I have I am able to have it redirect you if you have the cookie entered, at least i think and also I have an input box. Now If anyone could  help me with this that will be great.

Here is the code for the cookie

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}

function checkCookie()
{
var user=getCookie("username");
if (user!="")
  {
  window.location.assign("http://....")  //if the user has a cookie saved it will redirect them to a newpage
  }
else 
  {
  user = prompt("Please enter your name:",""); // I do not want a prompt I want a input box
  if (user!="" && user!=null)
    {
    setCookie("username",user,30);
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Here is the html for the input box:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <button id="trigger">enter</button>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript that make the input a variable:

```
  var trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");
trigger.addEventListener("click",
    function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");

}, false)
```

You don't have to use my html but to recap: I would like an input box not a pop up where users but some info for their cookie and if the info is in there it redirects them to another page.

How do make a string a cookie?
Or how do you make an input the cookie?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve at the end? Some kind of login?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a development house, it's a resource for people to ask questions about their problems. What is your question? What have you tried? What was the output when you tried it?

Comment: From what I understand, you just need to add an input to the page, and set its value if the cookie exists?

Comment: @DBS not exactly  the input is set as teh cookie if no cookie exists , that is the only problem I am having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I see what I did wrong, thanks to some tips/help form @vulpus. I need to make the user input variable a parameter into the function then recall the check cookie function so it will redirect the user.

Cookie:

```
 <script>

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}

function checkCookie()
{
var user=getCookie("username");
if (user!="")
  {
  window.location.href ="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766590/how-to-save-user-text-input-html-input-as-cookie" 
  }
else 
  {
  if (user!="" && user!=null)
    {
    setCookie("username",user,30);
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

html input:

```
   <input type="text" id="userInput"=></input>
    <button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
```

makes userInput from the html a variable and enter it as a cookie:

```
<script>
        function test()
        {
            var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
            setCookie("username",userInput,30);
            checkCookie();
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the best I can understand about your question:

```
<div id="container">
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button id="trigger">enter</button>
</div>
```

And your js:

```
var trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");
trigger.addEventListener("click",
    function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    setCookie("user",input.value,30) // Just getting the id is an object and you can access things in that object

}, false)
```

Comment: PS: You might want to take a crash course on JavaScript http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript is a good one)

Comment: This input box does not let me enter anything. why is that?

Comment: Let my try it my server and get back to you soon

Comment: It is saying that setCookie is not defined

Comment: I changed the http/.... to a real link and entered a word in the box and clicked enter and I was not redirected

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43852/discussion-between-vulpus-and-user2330624)